# In formik, shorthand input field is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

In Formik, I try to use {...formik.getFieldProps('email')} on my input field
instead of using value, onChange, and onBlur. But it's not working.

This works :

```js
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value={formik.values.email} onChange={formik.handleChange} onBlur={formik.handleBlur} />
```

But this doesn't :

```js
<input id="email" type="text" {...formik.getFieldProps("email")} />
```

Code is here : https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-pb-with-getfieldprops-83tze?fontsize=14

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: If you console.log(formik.getFieldProps("email")), you will notice it is an array of two objects, not an object. Just follow the docs and do this rather onChange={formik.handleChange} value={formik.values.email}

Comment: Thank you MiDas for your reply. I looked at the console, and I saw it is an array of twi objects, but with the expression {...array} am I not supposed to explode the array ? I would like to avoid putting onChange={formik.handleChange} value={formik.values.email} because it is too verbose and I would like to use the shorthand instead. But it doesn't work...

Comment: I do get your request but what you are asking for is impossible.

Comment: I think it should be though as it is mentioned on the documentation : https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/tutorial#getfieldprops but for some reason I can't make it work...

Comment: Ensure you are on the latest version currently 2.0.3. if the issue persist then file an issue in the official repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MiDas said, what you are doing should work if you are on latest version.

I'll mention an even more concise alternative: the [Field](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field) component.

Field component handles the field property propagation for you.

Simple example:

```
<Field name="email" type="text" />
```

Notice that you don't need to do `{...formik.getFieldProps("email")}`, or any other "boilerplate".

---

Related to `Field` is `useField`, which can be used to make custom form components just as easy to use - no "boilerplate" needed.

A custom component:

```
function TextInputWithLabel({ label, ...props }) {
  // useField() returns [formik.getFieldProps(), formik.getFieldMeta()]
  // which we can spread on <input> and also replace ErrorMessage entirely.
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);
  return (
    <>
      <label
        htmlFor={props.id || props.name}
        css={{ backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor }}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
      <input className="text-input" {...field} type="text" {...props} />
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
<TextInputWithLabel name="input1" label="Random comment" />
```

As seen in [code from codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-fieldarray-from-docs-1-p4chd).

Comment: Thank you ! It's a nice alternative. But I also would like to know why {...formik.getFieldProps('email')} doesn't work and show errors here : https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-pb-with-getfieldprops-83tze?fontsize=14 . I definitely get error messages on the console even though I use Formik latest version. As Midas said I sent an issue on the official repo (https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1992) but no answer yet.

Comment: @AlexB - I've put the following comment on that repo: *""it's not working" isn't enough information to help you. Describe exactly what you did, what you expected to happen, and what did happen."*

Comment: @AlexB - also, your code sandbox seems to work for me.  When I enter "aa@aa.com" - a valid email - there is no error message. "aa" says its bad, which is correct. OTOH, there also *isn't* a message when it first appears - there should be, as it is empty. Maybe have to do something to trigger an update. If add characters, then delete them, get the empty error message.

Comment: @AlexB - I'm testing on latest Chrome, under Windows 10.