# Formik Form validation in react

Tags: formik

I have implemented form validation with formik and react. I am using material-UI.

```
   <Formik
    initialValues={{ name: '' }}
    onSubmit={values => {
        console.log('submitting', values);
    }}
    validate={values => {
        alert();
        let errors = {};
        if (!values.name) {
            errors.name = 'Name is required';
        }
        return errors;
    }}>

    {({
        handleSubmit,
        handleChange,
        values,
        errors
    }) => (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <input name="name"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name="name"
                        value={values.name}
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Name">
                    </input>
                    {errors.name &&
                        <span style={{ color: "red", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                            {errors.name}
                        </span>
                    }
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        )}
</Formik>
```

Above code is working fine for normal input tags but it is not working for **Select** and **TextField** material widgets.

Is there a compatibility issue with material UI ?
Please help.

Comment: Formik is not really compatible with anything that doesn't accept its props exactly as provided.  I find the best method is to build my own components which accept all the Formik props and implement them using whichever elements I want within those components, and then passing them as the ```component``` prop on a ```<Field/>``` component.

Comment: @ChrisB - do you have a codesandbox or other online code snippet repo, showing some Formik-compatible components you've built? I've been [testing Formik examples online](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-fieldarray-from-docs-1-p4chd) as I learn how to use it. (You can hopefully see my other sandboxes from that one, via my account.) Formik docs are lagging behind best practices for the hook-based v2 of Formik.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris B. commented, the solution is to wrap each desired element inside a React component that has what Formik requires. In the case of Material-UI, [Gerhat on GitHub has created some of those components](https://github.com/gerhat/material-ui-formik-components).

You can use those by downloading the source from the github link above. There is also a usage example there, showing how to use Gerhat's "wrapper" for a Material TextField and a Select.

In Gerhat's usage example, `TextField` is a component in that github repo; it isn't the Material UI TextField directly; it is a Formik-compatible "wrapper" around the Material TextField widget.

By looking at gerhat's source code, you can learn how to do the same for other Material widgets you need.

---

**HOWEVER, gerhat's implementation may not be the easiest for a beginner to understand.** Those wrappers are easy to *use*, but it may not be obvious from that code how to write your *own* wrappers for other widgets or components.

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58756480/199364) for a discussion of Formik's [`<Field>`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field) and [`useField`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useField). Those are easier ways to "wrap" existing React components. (Not specifically Material-UI widgets, but AFAIK, you can wrap those like any other React component.)

---

**If you do want to understand gerhat's approach,** here are some comments about the code you'll see at github.

[This is the source to TextField.jsx in that repo](https://github.com/gerhat/material-ui-formik-components/blob/master/src/TextField/TextField.jsx).

The "heart" of TextField.jsx, is its wrapping around Material's TextField. The generated virtual-DOM element (representing a Material TextField) is seen in these lines:

```
return (
    <TextField
      label={label}
      error={hasError}
      helperText={hasError ? errorText : ''}
      {...field}
      {...other}
    />
  )
```

See the source link above, for the details of how this is made compatible with Formik. IMHO, a fairly advanced understanding of both React and Formik is required, to understand what is being done there. This is why I mentioned `Field` and `useField` as the place to start, for writing your own "Formik-compatible wrappers".

One detail I'll mention. The implementation relies on a file `index.js` in the same folder as `TextField.jsx`, to map the default of `TextField.jsx`, which is `FTextField`, to the name `TextField`, which is how you refer to it in the "usage" code at the start of this answer. [SO Q&A about index.js file of a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44092341/199364).

index.js contents:

```
export { default as TextField } from './TextField'
```

The other two files in the TextField source folder are ".d.ts" files. [See this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21247278/199364) to understand those. You don't need them unless you are using TypeScript.